# Azure Databricks : Save file in Azure Datalake directory folder

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I would like to save file in my azure datalake gen2 directory by it is not working.

When I save the file without directory it works but with Directory "Data" it is not working.

Here is the code :

```
# Create a file in local data directory to upload and download
local_path = "./Data"
local_file_name = "quickstart" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

# Write text to the file
file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
file.write("Hello, World!")
file.close()

# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

# Upload the created file
with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Here is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Data/quickstart564851de-67a3-4b28-9af1-049298f26408.txt'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2012583145450168> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Write text to the file
----> 7 file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
      8 file.write("Hello, World!")
      9 file.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Data/quickstart564851de-67a3-4b28-9af1-049298f26408.txt'
```

The folder "Data" exist in my data lake :

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import FileSystemClient

file_system = FileSystemClient.from_connection_string(connect_str, file_system_name="flatdata")

paths = file_system.get_paths()

for path in paths:
    print(path.name + '\t')
```

output :

```
Data    
doto    
new.csv 
quickstart.csv  
quickstartc0afe722-3851-4f5a-a6fa-83fd97389c43.txt  
saved.csv
```

Here is the documentation from microsoft : [click here to see the Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can [Upload a file to a directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#upload-a-file-to-a-directory). Is this helpful for you?

Comment: Hi @hugo, since you run your code in azure databaricks, why do you not use pyspark? You can directly save file to data lake gen2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python#upload-a-file-to-a-directory). I've created a test to upload local file to a `folder` of my Azure data lake.
This is my local project file structure:
[image]

The file was uploaded to the `folder` of my Azure data lake.
[image]

This is my python code

```py
    import os, uuid
    from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

    # Create a file in local data directory to upload and download
    local_path = "./data"
    local_file_name = "quickstart" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
    upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

    # Write text to the file
    file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
    file.write("Hello, World!")
    file.close()
    
    #upload the file to the folder
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test10")

    directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("data")

    file_client = directory_client.create_file(local_file_name)

    local_file = open(upload_file_path, 'rb')

    file_contents = local_file.read()

    file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))

    file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

Comment: I have this error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/quickstart2d78e9d2-8cbc-4bbc-a43d-a3e33ce037b3.txt'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2416439453149044> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Write text to the file
---> 10 file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
     11 file.write("Hello, World!")
     12 file.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/quickstart2d78e9d2-8cbc-4bbc-a43d-a3e33ce037b3.txt'

Comment: Hi @hugo, please see my first picture is shows the local project file structure. There is a `data` folder under the relative path of my `upload_ADL.py`. Have you created the `data` folder in your local project ?

Comment: Hi @hugo Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )